# Copy a searched Object & Key from one HashMap into another

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I currently have two classes.
Main:

```
public class Main {

    HashMap <String, Product> products = new HashMap<String, Product>();

    public Main() {

        products.put("Cel403", (new Product("Chocolate sundae", 5.99)));
        products.put("Pi342", (new Product("Baseball Bat", 1.50)));
    }

    public void scan(String id) {

    }
```

Product:

```
public class Product {
    private String descr;
    private double price;

    public Product(String descr, double cost) {
        this.descr = descr;
        this.cost = cost;   
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (" Description: " + descr + " Cost: " + cost);
```

I currently have a products HashMap set up with a product ID as the string, and the Product class as the entitys(description of the item, price of item).

I want to create a method, which i've started setting up, called the scan method. This will allow an id to be typed into the parameter("Cel403" or "Pi342") and will then look through the HashMap (Maybe an iterator?) and retrieve the entry(Product) that this matches up to.
I want it to then COPY the (id)String and attached Product object into another HashMap called 'scanned'.
I can then run the scan method numerous times to add more products into the newly created 'scanned' HashMap. The 'scanned' HashMap will then contain the scanned objects with the id and i will be able to calculate the total cost of the items within the scanned HashMap.
Is this possible? And how would i go about doing this.

Comment: How would i go about doing it?

Comment: @Reddax What have you tried yet? You should share more details about your current design (for this computation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Map key has to be unique, if you do what you described, you'll only get one entry per Product id. If that's what you're looking for, you should do something like this

```
Map <String, Product> scanned = new HashMap<String, Product>();

public void scan(String id) {
    scanned.put(id, products.get(id));
}
```

Since I doubt that is what you need, you should rather make scanned a list containing scanned Products or pairs of Product and it's id.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Wow, that was easy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How would i go about getting all the prices from the products in the scanned, and adding them together?

Comment: double total = 0.0;
for(Product item : scanned) {
     total += item.getPrice();
}

Comment: that was for list solution. For map solution use Product item : scanned.getValues()

Comment: Well yes, you must have some way to access price in object Product. So make a method that returns that value and use it to calculate total.
Also, it's my mistake, it's values() not getValues(). But when you do stuff like this, you should use java API to find methods that you need.